# Error de código: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token

Tags: c++, array, struct

Por que estoy obteniendo esto:

```
array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
```

En esta linea de código:

```
char celda[fila][columna];
```

El código que tengo es este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <list>
#include <stack>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h> 

using namespace std;

int fila=0, columna=0, i , j = 0;
int fila_;

void matriz(){
    string arc = "registro.txt";
    string linea;



ifstream archivo(arc, ifstream::in);   

        while(!archivo.eof()){
            archivo >> linea;                                                           
            if(fila == 0){
                columna = linea.size();
            }              
            fila++;                                         
        }

        int fila_ = fila-1;     

        archivo.close();
}

struct laberinto
{
    char celda[fila][columna]; //ERROR
    char *operator[](char c)
    {
        return celda[c];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

El error es muy claro; traducido, viene a ser, *mas o menos*:

> El limite de la *formación* no es un literal entero, antes de `]`

Aparte de que algunos compiladores nos permitan usar variables al declarar formaciones ... el uso que le estás dando no tiene lógica. El tamaño de todos los tipos **tiene que ser conocido en tiempo de compilación** ... y tu estás intentado definir un tipo como de tamaño **dependiente** de una variable.

Aunque tu compilador soportara los `VLA` (Variable Lenght Array, Formación de tamaño variable), al usarlo al declarar una `struct` ... ¿ como sabrá el compilador el tamaño de tu `struct laberinto` ?

En tu caso concreto, tendrás que usar algún tipo de reserva dinámica de memoria (junto al uso de constructores y destructores), o hacer uso de algunas de las clases de la librería estandar:

Usando memoria dinamica:

```
struct laberinto {
  char **celda;
  ~laberinto( ) { delete[] celda; }
  laberinto( int fil, int cols ) : celda( new char*[fil * cols] ) { }
};
```

Usando clases de la libreria:

```
#include <vector>

struct laberinto {
  std::vector< char * > celda;
  ~laberinto( ) { delete[] celda; }
  laberinto( int fil, int cols ) : celda( fil * cols, nullptr ) { }
};
```

Lo que no puedes hacer, de ninguna manera, es declarar un tipo con un tamaño que dependa de ciertas variables.